# object has no attribute 'NamedWindow'

Tags: opencv, opencv3.1

```
import cv2 as cv
cv.NamedWindow("window_a", cv.CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
```

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'NamedWindow'

What is the analogue of this function in OpenCV 3?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Read the [doc](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga5afdf8410934fd099df85c75b2e0888b) and check the [tutorials](http://docs.opencv.org/master/dc/d2e/tutorial_py_image_display.html):

```
cv2.namedWindow('name')
```

> By default, the flag is cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE. But if you specify flag to be cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL, you can resize window.

Comment: what problem, exactly? Note the lowercase "n" in "**n**amedWindow"